# How to calculate Spark driver and executor memory in local machine?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, executor

I am a beginner with spark, generally in some executions with a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space is raised:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)
java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:348)
org.apache.parquet.bytes.HeapByteBufferAllocator.allocate(HeapByteBufferAllocator.java:32)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutivePartList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1696)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:925)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextFilteredRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:956)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:126)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:225)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:207)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator$$anon$1.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:61)
```

I have looked for what could be due to the lack of `--driver-memory` and `--executor-memory` args, this spark is hosted in a docker container, and the pyspark script runs with spark-submit:

```
docker exec -it pyspark_container \
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit \
    /spark_files/mapping.py;
```

My computer specifications:

8 cores
30GB ram
1.2TB ssd

I would like to know if it is possible and if it makes sense to increase these args since I am not in a cluster, and how to do the allocation calculation.

Really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you edit your question and add with which command you had this error? Did you use a REPL like `spark-shell` or `pyspark`? Or did you submit your command using `spark-submit`?

Comment: Thanks! this spark is in a docker container, and all the scala/pyspark files runs with spark-shell and spark-submit command(via airflow BashOperator)

Comment: Allright great! Please show an example of your spark-submit command, that will help to answer your question :) I'm mainly interested in what your `--master` and `--driver-memory` and `--executor-memory` arguments are, but seeing the whole command will be most useful.

Comment: Done! Note that i didn't include the driver and executor arguments, since i don't know the calculation of their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using a `--master` argument in your `spark-submit` command, you're using Spark in local mode. That means that all the driver and executor processes happen on the same machine.

In that case, the `--executor-memory` argument is not used. It is the `--driver-memory` argument that enable your local cluster to have more memory.

As we don't know what your data looks like, it is a bit hard to say what a proper size would be to choose here. The default value of `--driver-memory` is 1g. Since you have 30G of RAM on your machine, you can increase this.

Try something like:

```
docker exec -it pyspark_container \
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit \
    --driver-memory Xg \
    /spark_files/mapping.py;
```

where `X` is a number that makes sense for your data. If you have the whole machine to yourself, you can try using a big chunk of the available memory, like `--driver-memory 25g`.

Comment: the data is a 30GB json file hosted in S3, i'm gonna try with 16GB of driver memory and see the results. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it to work? :)

Comment: It worked! thank you:)